# Python. How can i split DataFrame into list with 2 components?

Tags: python, dataframe, split

I want to split DataFrame like below. DataFrame contains strings. and i want to split each strings into 2 lists

```
Input :

        AGE
0 '1 years 2 days ago'
1 '3 days 4 mins ago'
2 ' 5 mins 6 secs ago'


OUTPUT:
         AGE
0 [1, years], [2, days]
1 [3, days], [4, mins]
2 [5, mins], [6, secs]
```

Comment: Hey! If you got what you wanted please consider accepting one of the answers!

Answer (score 2):

Use `extract`:

```
>>> df['AGE'].str.extract(r'(\d+ \w+) (\d+ \w+)') \
             .applymap(str.split).apply(lambda x: [x[0], x[1]], axis=1) \
             .rename('AGE').to_frame()

                       AGE
0  [[1, years], [2, days]]
1   [[3, days], [4, mins]]
2   [[5, mins], [6, secs]]
```

Comment: It works well. but is it possible that column 0 and 1 is unified into 1 column?

Comment: @marsss. I updated my answer. What you get is a real list of list that's why `[ ]` enclose the column value.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly more easy to read solution:

```
# Creating the Dataframe objects
df = pd.DataFrame({'AGE':['1 years 2 days ago', '3 days 4 mins ago','5 mins 6 secs ago']})
final_df = pd.DataFrame()

# splitting into 4 separate columns
df = df['AGE'].str.split(' ', n=4, expand=True)

# Grouping into lists
final_df['first'] = df.iloc[:, [0,1]].values.tolist()
final_df['second'] = df.iloc[:, [2,3]].values.tolist()

print(final_df)
```

Output:

```
        first         second
0  [1, years]  [2, days]
1   [3, days]  [4, mins]
2   [5, mins]  [6, secs]
```